# Webpack dev server with proxy does not handle redirects

Tags: reactjs, webpack, axios

I am developing a react application. For development I am using webpack dev server. My backend application is a spring boot. When I make a request and I am not authenticated the backend redirects me to the login page (`localhost:8080/login`).

My webpack dev server runs on port `3000`. All my api call are redirected to the backend using a proxy from the devserver.

```
devServer: {
historyApiFallback: true,
contentBase: './',
proxy: [{
  context: ["/api"],
  target: "http://localhost:9090"
}],
changeOrigin: true,
secure: false
```

When I access a protected resource and I am not authenticated, for example `localhost:3000/api/test`, I am redirected to `localhost:8080/login` and I can see 2 request: a 302 request and a 200 request to `/login`. The problem is that the dev server does not actually do the redirect and does not show the login page. When serving the content from my spring boot application the redirect is done.

Is this a problem related to webpack dev server or is there something wrong in my understanding of the proxy mechanism?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Interested in this at the moment. Have an issue with where I would like to be able to handle redirects with webpack but can't find any resources around it. Maybe it isn't possible :(